# How to prevent website from going to top when jQuery menu button is being clicked?

Tags: jquery, animation, menu

I am working on the mobile version of my friends band page, here is the very beta version http://pandino.pl/msys

I've used some scripts found on the web, and now I am wondering how to prevent the page going to everytime when the menu button is clicked... I mean when you click "About band" page goes to top, but the content is showed. How to prevent it?

Any ideas? Or am I just doing something wrong with that scripts?

Comment: You can also use href="javascript:void(0);" instead of href="#".

Comment: href="javascript:void(0);" - that helped! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prevent the default behavior of your link:

```
$('#menu a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```